# Average Value of Subgraph in r

Tags: r, igraph

The Data looks like this

```
library(igraph)
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,3,2,NA,6,7)
Value<- c(1,0,0.5,0.5,0,-1,-1,-0.5)
Data <- data.frame(From,To, Value)
Network <- graph.data.frame(Data[,c("From","To")])
Network<- Network - "NA"
plot(Network)
```

Now i would like to know the AverageValue of the Partial Graph they are in and at it to the initial Dataframe. 
At the end it should look like this:

```
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,3,2,NA,6,7)
Value<- c(1,0,0.5,0.5,0,-1,-1,-0.5)
AverageTreeValue<- c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,-0.833,-0.833,-0.833)
FinalData <- data.frame(From,To, Value, AverageTreeValue)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `clusters` function to compute connected components in your graph, `aggregate` to compute the mean value for each of these clusters, and `merge` to combine the two together:

```
Data$group <- clusters(Network)$membership
(FinalData <- merge(Data, aggregate(Value~group, Data, mean), by="group"))
#   group From To Value.x    Value.y
# 1     1    1 NA     1.0  0.4000000
# 2     1    2  1     0.0  0.4000000
# 3     1    3  2     0.5  0.4000000
# 4     1    4  3     0.5  0.4000000
# 5     1    5  2     0.0  0.4000000
# 6     2    6 NA    -1.0 -0.8333333
# 7     2    7  6    -1.0 -0.8333333
# 8     2    8  7    -0.5 -0.8333333
```

Alternately, you could use `match` to perform the merge and get some more control over the names of the generated column:

```
groups <- clusters(Network)$membership
means <- aggregate(Value~group, data.frame(Value=Data$Value, group=groups), mean)
Data$AverageTreeValue <- means$Value[match(groups, means$group)]
Data
#   From To Value AverageTreeValue
# 1    1 NA   1.0        0.4000000
# 2    2  1   0.0        0.4000000
# 3    3  2   0.5        0.4000000
# 4    4  3   0.5        0.4000000
# 5    5  2   0.0        0.4000000
# 6    6 NA  -1.0       -0.8333333
# 7    7  6  -1.0       -0.8333333
# 8    8  7  -0.5       -0.8333333
```